# Delete VirtualBox snapshot's running state

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot

I have several VirtualBox snapshots depending in an tree-like hierarchy. Some of them however are saved running.

How can I drop the running state and just keep the harddisk state of snapshots inside the tree?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It is, however, possible to delete an intermediate snapshot with running state between non-running ones, like deleting any other state inbetween. So technically it don't seem a large issue, it's just not implemented it seems... Too sad.